# How to implement asp wizard-like control in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

I'd like to have a navigation area on the left side of the window that would consist of a series of buttons arranged vertically.  On the right side I'd like to display a view that would depend on the button clicked in the left side navigation area.  That is, the content of the view on the right side would be determined based on the currently selected (clicked on) button in the navigation area on the right side.

Could someone please point me in the right directions?  My experience is with MFC, WinForms, ansd ASP.  However, this is the first time that I need to tackle WPF.

I've read Josh Smith's article on MVVM but his example does not really illustrate what I'm after.

As I mentioned above, I'd like to click a button on the left side and then display a corresponding view on the right side.  Every button on the left side would trigger displaying of a different view on the right side.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, navigation between "pages" is used when there's a concept of a back/forward navigation, like on the Web. For this style, this [walk-through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752299.aspx) is useful.

In your case, it looks more like you have a navigation bar and no back button. I would structure this as a single `Window` application, where on the left you display the selected `UserControl`. Each `UserControl` would have its own ViewModel. So would the NavBar `UserControl`.

Main window could have its own MainViewModel that would orchestrate child ViewModels... but I would also look into various MVVM frameworks that provide a Messaging capability, which would enable ViewModels to talk among themeselves.

Hope that puts you on the right path. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  It looks that either NavigationWindow (described in 'walk-through') or Paul Stovell's blog about Frame (pointed to by sa_ddam213) will do the job for me.  Thanks to both of you.